# Running spring boot application in AWS and only allowing access via the AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

I want to run a spring boot application in aws (using ec2 or elastic beanstalk); this application has REST endpoints and I want to secure it such that only the AWS API Gateway has the permissions to invoke the endpoints (i.e. no public access and no access from other services)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure API Gateway to use a [Client-Side SSL Certificate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html). Then you have to configure your back-end to reject any requests that don't include that certificate.